# Error when install h5py on my Windows11, Visual Studio Code, Python 3.10.4, 64-bt

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, h5py

I meet error when install `h5py` on my **Windows11, Visual Studio Code, Python 3.10.4, 64-bt**

**Please see error detail at the very end of the post**

My working process as below (i.e., the way I tired to solve the error):

**1st: Upgrade pip, wheel and setuptools**: They already satisfied as shown below

```
PS C:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages> pip3 install --upgrade pip
>>
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (22.1.2)
```

```
PS C:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages> pip install --upgrade wheel          
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (0.37.1)
```

```
PS C:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages>  pip install --upgrade setuptools
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (63.2.0)
```

**2nd: Installing virtualenv**: Already downloaded

```
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in c:\users\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (20.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six<2,>=1.9.0 in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from virtualenv) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: platformdirs<3,>=2 in c:\users\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from virtualenv) (2.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.2 in c:\users\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from virtualenv) (3.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.1 in c:\users\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages (from virtualenv) (0.3.5)
```

**3rd install C++ build tool**: Already download and ready to use as shown below
[image]

**4th try install package through terminal**: Get error
`pip install h5py==3.1.0` and `pip install --no-binary=h5py h5py==3.1.0`

Comment: Are you fixed on using python 3.10? `h5py` version 3.1 requires `numpy=1.19.3` which does not have wheels for python 3.10, only up to 3.9 and building numpy from source on windows is not easy because you would need to take care of quite some dependencies which you would need to build manually before

Comment: @FlyingTeller Thank you for clarify! That makes so much sense. Yep, so far I only use python 3.10 (all my packages installed within it). Is that means I need to install python 3.9 (for example) set the path & re-install everything (the same as I done before), but only install numpy=1.19.3. (I'm currently in numpy = 1.22.3)? Or if you could kindly provide me with a better suggestion, I would be very appreciated!

Comment: If you are fixed on needing h5py, then using an older python version for that project seems to be the best way. This would indeed mean that you would have to install all packages that you need to that python version again. I suggest though that you use a virtual environment manager like conda to handle your different python versions. Alternatively, if you are lucky, you could get away with the newer numpy version, no guarantee though that h5py works as expected then, this would mean doing `pip install --no-deps h5py==3.1.0`.

Comment: @FlyingTeller Thank you so so much again for pointing out that "python version problem", otherwise I would make a detoured for a much longer time! I install python 3.9.13 64-bit and it works! Would you wanna put your suggestion to "answer" section so that I can accept you talented idea?  :)

Comment: You are welcome. There might have been some super complicated way to actually compile your required numpy version from source, but it would have been well beyond the scope of what you actually need. I have added my suggestions as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`h5py` version 3.1 requires `numpy=1.19.3` which does not have wheels for python 3.10, only up to 3.9 and building `numpy` from source on Windows is not easy because you would need to take care of quite some dependencies which you would need to build manually before (see e.g. `libraries mkl_rt not found` in your error message).

I would therefore suggest to either:

- downgrade your python version, then install all versions as set in yur question
- consider if a newer version of `h5py` (with a different `numpy` requirement) would also work for you
- Try `pip install --no-deps h5py==3.1.0` and install a `numpy` version compatible with your python separately. This has a high chance of not working, though.

The first option is probably the best, since you most likely have reasons why you need that specific h5py version. If you find yourself often needing different python versions for different projects, consider using a virtual environment manager like `conda`

Answer (score -1):

*A quick way to resolve the issue without troubleshooting.*

**Please follow the steps and update the same.**

1. Uninstall all the packages you are currently having problems with.
2. Create a virtual environment: [How to create a virtual environment link here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-virtual-environment/)
3. Install all packages inside the virtual environment.
4. Test by importing them and see if it works.

Comment: `After successfully creating the virtual environment -> Install Anaconda or IDE there` does not make any sense. You cannot install anaconda into a python virtualenv

Comment: I had an issue once with python 2.7 and 3.  Installing the packages inside the virtual environment worked for me. Irrespective of the location of the IDE. Excuse me for my mistake.